# Работа с Access в C# (WinForms)

Tags: c#, база-данных, ms-access

Как можно изменять значения ячеек базы access программно, а не через DataGridView?
Например, на форме несколько textbox'ов, они заполняются пользователем и после нажатия на button поля textbox'ов сохраняются в базу access

Comment: Дополните свой вопрос. Возможно немного кода поможет дать Вам ответ.

Comment: Не важно где показываются данные: в `DataGridView` или `TextBox` - код для работы с БД совершенно одинаковый в обоих случаях.

Comment: @DenisBubnov http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0

Comment: @4per, спасибо, не видел. Но я придерживаюсь внутристрочного выделения, когда используется выделение кода для *«кода и кодообразных сущностей»*, в дальнейшем буду иметь в виду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приведу простой пример, кликаем на `button` - сохраняем из `textbox`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
  {
    try
    {
      conn.Open();
      string query = "UPDATE [таблица] SET [имя_колонки] = ? WHERE id = ?";
      var accessUpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
      accessUpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("имя_колонки", textBox1.Text); // текст
      accessUpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", 1); // тут напишите свой ид 
      da.UpdateCommand = accessUpdateCommand;
      da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
      conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      // обработка исключения 

      if (conn != null && conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
      {
         conn.Close();
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

`connectionString` - это строка подключения к базе.

Также можно без `AddWithValue`, просто сразу в строку пишите, что Вам нужно вместо знаков вопроса. Про строку, чтобы было понятнее, к примеру:

```
int id = 1;
string query = "UPDATE [что_обновляем] SET [имя_обновляемой_колонки] =" + 
                  textBox1.Text + " WHERE id = " + id;
```